# how to use xPath for following

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I got div "rso" data in php Dom by using getElementById('rso')  but php does not allow to get by "ClassName" , **i need to get all "child" of**  `<div class =srg>` and then tag "href" inside that.

```
<div id=”rso”>
    <div class= “_Nid”>
        <div class = “srg”>
            <div class =”g”> 
                <div class=”rc”>
                    <h3 class = “r”>
                        <a href >
                    </h3>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class =”g”>...</div>
            <div class =”g”>...</div>
            <div class =”g”>...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

can you please tell how it can be done. or what xPath will be used if it can work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<div id="rso">
    <div class="_Nid">
        <div class="srg">
            <div class="g"> 
                <div class="rc">
                    <h3 class="r">
                        <a href="http://my.site.com/lol.txt" >
                    </h3>
                    <h3 class="r">
                        <a href="http://my.site.com/lol2.txt" >
                    </h3>
                    <h3 class="r">
                        <a href="http://my.site.com/lol23.txt" >
                    </h3>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="g">...</div>
            <div class="g">...</div>
            <div class="g">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$domxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$filtered =  $domxpath->query('//div[@class="srg"]//a/@href');
foreach ($filtered as $item) {
    echo "$item->value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below `XPath`:

```
//div[@class="srg"]//a/@href
```